# Page not found in Django (404)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a little problem with Django 2.0. In my case the debugger responded with this message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
```

Using the URLconf defined in `bajkowo.urls`, Django tried the following URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
bajki/
```

But that resulted in an error:

> The empty path didn't match any of these.
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

I have checked the views and URLs, but I could not find a bug or a typo. Could anyone check my code?

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('bajki/', include('bajki.urls')),
]
```

**bajki/urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('bajki/',views.lista_bajek, name='lista_bajek'),
]
```

**bajki/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def lista_bajek(request):
    return render(request, 'bajki/lista_bajek.html', {})
```

The `def lista_bajek` should respond with a blank website, but returns a 404 error code. Of course, I did create the `bajki/templates/bajki/lista_bajek.html` file.

Comment: Well, you have only defined /bajki/bajki/, but you are going to / - what did you expect?

Comment: You haven't defined url for empty path (http://localhost:8000/). You only defined `admin/` and `bajki/bajki/`. Add url for `''`, eg. `path('', views.lista_bajek, name='index')` to urls.

Comment: Borut its working thank you!